# Insufficient Privileges to create a sandbox

Tags: permissions, sandbox

You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.

++I am System administrator.

Answer (score 1):

In System Administrator profile you need system level permissions to create sandbox

Comment: is it possible to create a sandbox in developer(test) environment

Comment: No, We can create Sandbox from Production Org Only. Thanks,

Comment: i have small doubt..if i create a sandbox in production can i upload new outbound change sets in test org..(i want deploy a single custom object in production)

Comment: Yes, you need to first create connect between sandbox and production, after that you deploy code from sandbox to production or production to sandbox. Thanks,

Comment: how to find target organization..i always got this error " This organization isn't authorized to upload change sets to other organizations. For authorization, contact the deployment connections administrators on the organizations where you want to upload changes."....it shows in target organization when i am upload components...